# How to create unicode slug for unicode title?

Tags: php, url, unicode, url-rewriting, seo

I want to sanitize blog titles with unicode characters in url. I need to replace invalid characters and spaces with "-" for better seo rewriting like this.

```
        http://example.com/это-моя-хорошая
```

Can anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Please define "invalid characters".

Comment: i don't want the characters like . , [] {} / ? in my url. If user post the title with these characters i want to change it to '-' for better seo.

Comment: I've no idea which language u are using, since i don't see a C# tag. But in C# i would do Url.Encode()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this algorithm for an SEO-friendly Unicode URL:

1. Convert the text to Unicode Normalization Form C, i.e. precomposed characters.
2. Use a regular expression with Unicode character classes to replace each non-letter non-digit character with a space.
3. Remove leading, trailing and double spaces.
4. Shorten.
5. Replace spaces with hyphens.

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm. I started looking after normalization of unicode characters and found this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php . Is this the correct function to normalize or are there any other library or function that could normalize unicode characters?

Comment: @uttam That's right. In PHP you can use Normalizer::normalize.