# Sanitizing Unicode strings for URL slugs (Ruby/Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, sanitization, slug

I have UTF-8 encoded post titles which I'd rather show using the appropriate characters in slugs. An example is [Amazon Japan's URL here](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E4%BB%BB%E5%A4%A9%E5%A0%82-203135011-%E3%83%8C%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%82%AF-%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AD/dp/B000KF9E6Q/ref=pd_sim_vg_5?ie=UTF8&refRID=0JK7MGYG8GTGBJ6NMTSA).

How can any arbitrary string be converted to a safe URL slug such as this, with Ruby (or Rails)?

(There are some [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511254/how-to-create-unicode-slug-for-unicode-title) [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668854/sanitizing-strings-to-make-them-url-and-filename-safe) posts, but nothing I could find for Ruby.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714196/ruby-url-encoding-string) it seems like a solution is this:

```
require 'open-uri'
str = "\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
puts URI::encode(str)
```

[Here is the documentation for open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html). and [here is some info on utf-8 encoded url schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters).

EDIT: having looked into this more I noticed encode is just an alias for `URI.escape` which is [documented here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html). example taken from the docs below:

```
require 'uri'

enc_uri = URI.escape("http://example.com/?a=\11\15")
p enc_uri
# => "http://example.com/?a=%09%0D"

p URI.unescape(enc_uri)
# => "http://example.com/?a=\t\r"

p URI.escape("@?@!", "!?")
# => "@%3F@%21"
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for?

EDIT #2: I was interested and kept looking a little more, [according to the comments](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=comments) ryan bates' [railscasts on friendlyid](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) also seems to work with chinese characters.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try experimenting with the core functionality inside friendlyid.